# read and write a text file locally using chromium

Tags: html, api, chromium, filereader, filewriter

I am running a web application from a local folder using Chromium.

Let's say I have my application contained in the following folder:

C:/Myfolder/App

I also know how to read a text file using the HTML5 APIs using a

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="fileElem" />
```

now I would like to know if I can read the file without the user having to select the file I am trying to read. The file is always contained in the following folder:

C:/Myfolder/App/Files

a subfolder of the folder containing the HTML that defines my application so there will not be any security restrictions and the file is always run through chromium locally. The file I am trying to read is a text file. Can I also modify and write the file in the same location? If yes would you be so kind to provide some example code?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `TChromium.Options.FileAccessFromFileUrls` to `STATE_ENABLED` and then you can use your normal AJAX functions on `file://`-Urls.

If you are using jQuery, you could use this code:

```
$.get('file:///c:/Myfolder/App/files/content.xml',function(data){
  console.log(data);
})
```